# 'Set-AzureWebsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to run following powershell cmdlet on my azurewebsite

```
 public string RunPowerShellScript()
    {

        try
        {
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            //Here's how you add a new script with arguments            
            Command myCommand = new Command("Set-AzureWebsite");
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", "rmssimple");
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("HostNames ", "@('test.posxyz.com', 'xyz.com')");

            pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
            var results = pipeline.Invoke();

            return Content(results[0].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

but i get bellow error

> The term 'Set-AzureWebsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score -1):

firts question : why do you wan tto do it like that? second, if you want to do it , you need to import the module first and the Powershell tools need to be installed. Importing the module is as follwos in PoSh : import-module Azure

Comment: I have installed Powershell tools, Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell etc

Comment: when i try to run command in powershell import-module Azure, it gives me error "The specified modle "Azure" was not found

Comment: the powershell tools have a separate download : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ see the commandline section

Comment: but why do you want to call the powershell commands from .Net code?

Comment: My website is deployed in azure and i want to activate subdomain programtically instead of using azure portal thats why i want to call powershell comands

Comment: you'd better use the REST API or the MAML nuget package (its a wrapper around the REST API) http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/ . If you still want to use it explicitly from Pwoershell try force importing the module from the location directly. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\azure.psd1) Hope this helps